# How to add listener/update build in Persistent_bottom_nav_bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, navbar

I am using [Persistent Bottom Navigation Bar Version 2](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2) package in my application, In this

[image: Picture]

as you can see I have 10 items in the cart. I can add and remove items from my cart. the count is not updated until I click any of the bottom nav bar items.

Expected Result:

when I run cart API, I receive data. on the bottom bar number of items will be updated automatically without clicking on the bottom nav bar

Here's my example code

```
  import 'dart:async';

class BootomNaviBar extends StatefulWidget {
  bool? cameFromSplash;
  BootomNaviBar({super.key, this.cameFromSplash = false});

  @override
  State<BootomNaviBar> createState() => _BootomNaviBarState();
}

class _BootomNaviBarState extends State<BootomNaviBar> {
  CartBloc cartBloc = CartBloc();
  CartManager cartManager = CartManager();

  final int _cartitems = 0;

  PersistentTabController? _controller;


  @override
  void initState() {
    cartBloc = context.read<CartBloc>();

    initConnectivity();

    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
    _controller!.addListener(() {});
    super.initState();
  }


 List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
     Screen1(),
     Screen2(),
     Screen3(),
     CartScreen(),
     Screen5(), 
     Screen6(),
    
    ];
  }

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                NAV BAR ITEMS                               */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navbarItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
         AppImages.pic1,
          height: 5.h,
          color:  AppColors.grey,
        ),
        title: "Screen",
        activeColorPrimary: AppColors.kred,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        routeAndNavigatorSettings:
            const RouteAndNavigatorSettings(initialRoute: '/'),
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
          AppImages.pic1,
          color:  AppColors.kgrey,
        ),
        title: ("Screen"),
        activeColorPrimary: AppColors.kred,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
           AppImages.pic1,
          height: 5.h,
          color:AppColors.kgrey,
        ),
        title: ("Screen"),
        activeColorPrimary: AppColors.kred,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: cartManager.cartCount == 0
            ? SvgPicture.asset(
                 AppImages.pic1,
                height: 5.h,
                color:
                   AppColors.kgrey,
              )
            : badges.Badge(
                badgeContent: Text(
                  cartManager.cartCount.toString(),
                
                  style: sans12light.copyWith(color: AppColors.kblack),
                ),
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  AppImages.pic1,
                  height: 5.h,
                  color: _controller!.index == 3
                      ? AppColors.kred
                      : AppColors.kgrey,
                ),
              ),
       
        activeColorPrimary: AppColors.kred,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
         Pic1,
          height: 5.h,
          color:  AppColors.kgrey,
        ),
        title: ("Cart"),
        activeColorPrimary: AppColors.kred,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        routeAndNavigatorSettings:
            const RouteAndNavigatorSettings(initialRoute: '/profileMenu'),
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
          "assets/icons/btb_more.svg",
          height: 5.h,
          color: _controller!.index == 5 ? AppColors.kred : AppColors.kgrey,
        ),
        title: ("Screen"),
        activeColorPrimary: AppColors.kred,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: AppColors.kwhite,
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            PersistentTabView(context,
             
                screens: _buildScreens(),
                popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
                popAllScreensOnTapAnyTabs: true,
                items: _navbarItems(),
                controller: _controller,
                stateManagement: false,
                // navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style6, onItemSelected: (index) {
                navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style8, onItemSelected: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _controller!.index = index;
              });
            }),
           
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class CustomNavBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? selectedIndex;

  final List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem>? items;

  final ValueChanged<int>? onItemSelected;

  const CustomNavBarWidget({
    super.key,
    this.selectedIndex,
    @required this.items,
    this.onItemSelected,
  });

  @override
  State<CustomNavBarWidget> createState() => _CustomNavBarWidgetState();
}

class _CustomNavBarWidgetState extends State<CustomNavBarWidget> {
  Widget _buildItem(PersistentBottomNavBarItem item, bool isSelected) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: IconTheme(
              data: IconThemeData(
                  size: 26.0,
                  color: isSelected
                      ? (item.activeColorSecondary ?? item.activeColorPrimary)
                      : item.inactiveColorPrimary ?? item.activeColorPrimary),
              child: isSelected ? item.icon : item.inactiveIcon ?? item.icon,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
            child: Material(
              type: MaterialType.transparency,
              child: FittedBox(
                child: Text(
                  item.title!,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: isSelected
                          ? (item.activeColorSecondary ??
                              item.activeColorPrimary)
                          : item.inactiveColorPrimary,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontFamily: 'Calibri',
                      fontSize: 12.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: widget.items!.map((item) {
            int index = widget.items!.indexOf(item);

            return Expanded(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  widget.onItemSelected!(index);
                },
                child: _buildItem(item, widget.selectedIndex == index),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```